# mysql_real_escape_string works in localhost but not on webserver

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that is inserting a record into a database after getting the data from a user-filled form. I developed on my local machine (WAMP server) and have the following code in my PHP script:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

        //connecting to db
        mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass") or die('save_failed');
        mysql_select_db("db") or die('save_failed');

        //inserting into table
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(name, email) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "' ) ") 
        or die('save_failed');
```

The script worked just as expected and the records were being successfully inserted into the table.

As soon as I moved the script to my webserver, I realized the values being stored in the database were empty strings. Removing `mysql_real_escape_string` fixed this.

Why is it that `mysql_real_escape_string` won't work on my webserver?

The database I'm working on hasn't changed. Even when developing locally, I was hitting my webserver DB.
PHP ver on localhost is 5.3.8 while on the webserver it is 5.2.

Does PHP 5.2 not support `mysql_real_escape_string`, and if so what is the alternative?

Comment: Why all error messages are called `save_failed`? How do you determine whether it was the connection, select database statement or insert query that failed?

Comment: I'm not too worried about that because those errors should be logged in the php log files (unless i'm mistaken)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass") or die('save_failed');` before `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: oh, wow...yeah. had no idea that function depended on a mysql connection. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You *first* need to connect to the database, *then* `mysql_real_escape` your strings. I suspect it works locally because PHP and your database are configured so they can automatically establish a connection when needed.

> http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string
>
> If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by `mysql_connect()` is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if `mysql_connect()` was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an `E_WARNING` level error is generated.

Apparently you should also activate error reporting and/or check your error logs.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual page for [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://es.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string):

> **Parameters**
>
> **unescaped_string**: The string that is to be escaped.
>
> **link_identifier:** The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the
>   last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is
>   found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with
>   no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING
>   level error is generated.

Your code uses `mysql_real_escape_string()` before calling `mysql_connect()`. That means that PHP is trying to open a connection to the MySQL server before than you think and you are not providing credentials or doing error checking. If it works in your development box, it's probably pure chance: your local server has default credentials at `php.ini` or a password-less MySQL account.

Move the *connecting to db* part to the top and you're done.