# php form post is empty

Tags: php, forms

I just started with the basics of html and php and hosted a tiny website on the server of a friend and erverything worked fine. Now I got my own server and I transfered all my website-data to this new server and only changed the `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` parts. A simple test with `mysql_query()` works, so the connection to my new database is alive (and yes, there is data in it).
However, a form post sends always empty forms:

```
login.php:
<form method="post">
<input name="user" type="text">
<button class="myButton" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">Login</button>
</form> 

<?php
$user=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
echo "user: ".$user;
?>
```

Here the username is empty.
I already tried changing the first line into this: `<form action="login.php" method="post">` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306870/php-form-post-always-empty), but this doesn't work. The URL of my loginpage looks like this: `subdomain.domain.de/login.php` and that's the same location-syntax I used on the server of my friend.

I also read about problematic `.htaccess`-configuration, but when I search for this file, I can't find it:

```
cd /
find . -name ".htaccess"
```

Hope someone can help me (I believe it's very simple)

Comment: Basic debugging: use var_export($_POST) to see what your page is receiving. Make it the first line of your php code.

Comment: @ David: this prints the correct form input

Comment: use mysqli functions and not mysql because it is deprecated also add 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);  for debuging at the first line of your posted data script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` requires an active MySQL connection in order for it to work correctly; if you aren't connected to the database, it will fail.

For more information you can check these posts

[mysql_real_escape_string stopped working when I moved my code to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808588/mysql-real-escape-string-stopped-working-when-i-moved-my-code-to-another-server)

and

[mysql_real_escape_string works in localhost but not on webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803522/mysql-real-escape-string-works-in-localhost-but-not-on-webserver)

Try to remove this function `mysql_real_escape_string` and then check again

change from

```
$user=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
```

to

```
$user=$_POST['user'];
```

Comment: Wow this is it! but... why? And why did it work on my friends server?

Comment: you can get the detail here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808588/mysql-real-escape-string-stopped-working-when-i-moved-my-code-to-another-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803522/mysql-real-escape-string-works-in-localhost-but-not-on-webserver

Answer (score 1):

me be your connection to mysql is empty , and  stop using **mysql** , use **mysqli** instead because mysql is **deprecated** and , check your mysql connection and try again it will work properly and use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

```
    <?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
      $user=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
      echo "user: ".$user;
  }
```

Comment: the if() statement is true